# Coffeescript class and Handlebars template and custom block helper

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, handlebars.js

When I use **Handlebars.compile** on a variable it works well, but when I put the function on a Coffee class property, it give me **undefined**, bug? Or I miss some basic java/coffee functionality?

There is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cl0udW4lk3r/BpY5b/

```
class Test
  template: Handlebars.compile (
    """
    {{#iterate data}}
        <p>{{data}}</p>
    {{/iterate}}
    """
  )

template = Handlebars.compile (
  """
  {{#iterate data}}
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  {{/iterate}}
  """
)
```

There is another fiddle with backbone in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Cl0udW4lk3r/D3FR9/20/

---- UPDATE -----

My first fiddle is solved (but the handlebars version was outdated), and the error was a stupid OOP inattention...

But! My second fiddle (and now that I've updated the first fiddle's handlebars resource, also my first fiddle..) give to me an error

> TypeError: callback is not a function

It seems that the callback part is not right processed... the error is the same both on coffee class or simple variable case...

Answer (score 3):

When you say this:

```
class Test
  template: ...
```

you're defining `template` as an instance property so you'd have to create an instance before you could look at `template`:

```
t = new Test
console.log(t.template)
```

Or you could dig the `template` out of `Test`'s prototype:

```
console.log(Test::template)
```

If you want `template` to be a class property then:

```
class Test
  @template: ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tvDpN/

---

Your second issue is related to a change in how Handlebars helpers get called. The last argument used to be the callback function and you'd use `fn.inverse` for the `{{else}}` block. The last argument to the helper is now an object with the function in `.fn` and the else-block function in `.inverse`. So for the latest versions of Handlebars, your helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'iterate', (context, callback) ->
    switch typeof context
        when 'object' then (callback(key: key, value: value) for own key, value of context).join ''
```

should looks more like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'iterate', (context, options) ->
    switch typeof context
        when 'object' then (options.fn(key: key, value: value) for own key, value of context).join ''
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NQZTG/

Comment: Oh, my mistake, thanks, the first fiddle works now, then I can't figure out why the second fiddle should not work, if you inspect it with firebug it give an error: callback is not a function...

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r: Have a look at my update. The arguments for Handlebars helpers changed, you're using the old argument format with a newer library.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're inspecting the `template` property of the `Test` class itself, instead of instantiating a new instance of the `Test` class and inspecting the property on that instance. The following should work:

```
$ ->
  console.log new Test().template
  console.log template
```